# Android Studio: Seperator Line with or text

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, adobe-xd

for my login screen i want to add a seperator line with an or tag in the middle of the line. 
I use Android Studio and Kotlin. I do the design in Adobe XD and this is how it should look like.

[image]

My idea is to use two views for the lines and one textView for the or.
Do you have better ideas?

Comment: To reduce number of `Views` you can use one line instead of two and put `TextView` with `centerInParent=true` and background filled with color of layouts background.

Comment: i used to do like your idea all the time